# Making two windows with separate files(?) in gvim

Tags: vim, split, window, buffer

I'm a beginner vi user. I don't know the terminology, but I want to split my gvim terminal(screen?) into 2 windows which each have 5 different files(buffers?). I can open the first 5 files in one window, then split to a second window, but I don't know how to open 5 more different files in the second window. I haven't been able to find this information. Normally I switch between files with `:n` and `:prev`.

To say it again: I want files 1-5 on a left window and files 6-10 on a right window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed have window-local argument lists:

```
:arglocal
:args file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
:vsplit
:arglocal
:args file6 file7 file8 file9 file10
```

This way, you can have one argument list (with files 1-5) for the left window, and another (with files 6-10) on a split right window. Commands like `:next` and `:first` in the windows are then independent of each other.

Comment: The arglist! Facepalm…

Comment: @romainl I've never used window-local arglists so far, but isn't it nice to discover that Vim has you covered!

Comment: What about a way to add an extra arg to the current local args?

Comment: @Stuart That would be `:argadd`, just as usual.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry, but is there a command similar to `:q` or `:wq` for a file in an arglist?

Comment: @Stuart Ah, come on, read the fine help! With `:argdelete`, you can remove files (pass `%` for the current one).

Comment: @Ingo Honestly, I read over it for quite a while and though `:argd` will remove it from the arglist, it doesn't quit/close the file and thought there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Buffers are global. It means that you can't have, say two vertical windows, housing two exclusive sets of buffers. The same applies to tabs, of course.

So, just use two instances: one on the left with files 1-5 and the other on the left with files 6-10.

Because the two instances are separated, you can safely use `:n` et `:prev` without "overflowing".

Comment: Are you saying all tabs in the same screen share the same buffers?

Comment: When you are in a window or a tab, whatever tab or window, you get access to the same list of buffers: there is only one buffer list per Vim instance and there's no way around it. You want two independent buffer lists so you *must* use two independent vim instances.

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are viewports for windows, windows are viewports for buffers. You can view any buffer in any window. I would not call it impossible to create some workaround though: e.g. you can create commands `:NEXT` and `:PREV` via `:command` and make them iterate only over buffers that were opened in this window via `:EDIT`: like in the code below. But I would highly suggest use some plugin that aids in buffer switching like [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) (I have `nnoremap ,b :CommandTBuffer<CR>` for buffer switching) and forget about highly inefficient `:next`/`:previous` commands.

```
function s:Edit(args)
    let w:winbuflist=get(w:, 'winbuflist', [bufnr('%')])
    execute 'edit' a:args
    let buf=bufnr('%')
    if index(w:winbuflist, buf) == -1
        call add(w:winbuflist, bufnr('%'))
    endif
endfunction
function s:Switch(direction)
    let buf=bufnr('%')
    let w:winbuflist=get(w:, 'winbuflist', [buf])
    let idx=index(w:winbuflist, buf)
    if idx==-1 || w:winbuflist ==# [buf]
        if idx == -1
            echohl ErrorMsg
            echomsg 'Current buffer was not opened using :E or was opened in another window'
            echohl None
        endif
        execute a:direction
        return
    elseif a:direction is# 'next'
        let idx += 1
        if idx == len(w:winbuflist)
            let idx=0
        endif
    elseif a:direction is# 'previous'
        let idx -= 1
        if idx == -1
            let idx=len(w:winbuflist)-1
        endif
    endif
    execute 'buffer' w:winbuflist[idx]
endfunction
function s:RemoveBuf(buf)
    for tab in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
        for win in range(1, tabpagewinnr(tab, '$'))
            call filter(getwinvar(win, 'winbuflist', []), 'v:val isnot '.a:buf)
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction

augroup BufWinList
    autocmd! BufWipeout * :call s:RemoveBuf(+expand('<abuf>'))
augroup END

"       \/\/\/\/\/\/\/ Warning: this is not a completion option. It also
"       \/\/\/\/\/\/\/ makes command do the expansion of its arguments.
command -complete=file -nargs=? -bar EDIT :call s:Edit(<q-args>)
command                -nargs=0 -bar NEXT :call s:Switch('next')
command                -nargs=0 -bar PREV :call s:Switch('previous')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you just need to perform several splits.

1. Split to 2 vertical windows: Ctrl-w v
2. In each window: Ctrl-w s (repeat it 4 times, to get 5 buffers)

You can move between windows with Ctrl-w j / Ctrl-w k

Comment: I only want two windows and I want files 1-5 in one window and files 6-10 in a different window, such that I can move between the files in my current window with `:n` and `:prev`.

Answer (score 0):

The `:split` command takes a file name, and opens that in a new, horizontally split window. (But you can also first just `:split` / `<C-W>s` / `<C-W>v`, and then `:edit` / `:next` another file.) Prepend `:vertical` (or shorter `:vsplit`) for vertical splitting. With this, you can create your desired layout.

To focus a different window, there are many mappings that start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, e.g. `<C-w>j` to go to the window below. See `:help CTRL-W` for the full list.

Comment: I am familiar with splitting. I tried to edit the question for clarification.

Comment: Ah, your question really wasn't clear. Please see my other answer.